# SELECT offset ,datetime('now','+offset minutes', 'localtime')

Tags: sqlite, datetime, offset, minute

This query i rebuild

```
SELECT time('now','+30 minutes')
```

to a more complex one where the offset (minutes) are my problem.

This query isn't working but how i get it done.

```
SELECT offset, datetime('now','+offset minutes', 'localtime')
FROM database 
WHERE 1
```

How to put the offset value correct between '+offset minutes'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'+offset'` is a string that contains the characters `+offset`.

In SQL, string concatenation is done with `||` (the number is automatically converted to a string):

```
SELECT offset,
       datetime('now', '+' || offset || ' minutes', 'localtime')
FROM database
WHERE 1
```